# Pandas dataframe array

Tags: python, arrays, pandas

I'm a new user of python and pandas and I I'm trying to turn a dataframe into a single line every possibilites in columns.

Origin (B) :

[Matrix of probabilities](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aw75t.png)

And I what I'm trying to obtain :

```
0-0     0-1     0-2      0-3     0-4      0-5     1-0     1-1 ..
3.87    1.79    3.5      2.2     1.04     0.39   2.09     9.48 ...
```

I have tried to start with a loop but I'm blocked there:

```
for i in range(6):
    for j in range(6):
       [print(i,"-",j,"-",B[i,j])]
```

result :

```
0 - 0 - 3.8781975861094464
0 - 1 - 2.0950303215526334
0 - 2 - 4.089533696073365
...
```

Thanks you for your help

Comment: how is B defined? Also, you seem to have an indention issue with your code - is that on purpose?

Comment: B is my matrix in an array and the identation error is just a copy/paste error from my code to stack overflow, sorry  . What I want to do now is to transpose that result into lines (like in my example) and put in a pandas dataframe.

Answer (score 0):

You need to indent - that is: move to the right - the second for-loop. Like so:

```
for i in range(6):
   for j in range(6):
      [print(i,"-",j,"-",B[i,j])]
```

Otherwise the first for loop will not work.
I hope hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, you want to build a single row dataframe where the columns are `'i-j'` with i and j being the indices in matrix B and the values being `B[i,j]`.

I would compute separately the column names and the values:

```
columns = [f'{i}-{j}' for i in range(6) for j in range(6)]
values = pd.concat([df[i] for i in df.columns]).values
result = pd.DataFrame([values], columns=columns)
```

it should give:

```
      0-0     0-1    0-2      0-3      0-4      0-5    1-0  ...  
0    3.87    1.79    3.5      2.2     1.04     0.39   2.09  ...
```

(I could not test the values because the data is only given as an **image** and thus cannot be copied)